# Nondimesionalization of the ODE for a falling object subject to Quadratic Drag Law.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE describing an object falling through the air subject to the quadratic drag law:
$$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-g -\dfrac{\beta}{m}v|v|$$
where $\beta$ is a dimensional drag coefficient, how would we go about  nondimensionalizing it? I'm really stuck on finding $v_o$ and $t_o$ s.t. $v(t) = \tilde{v}(t)v_o $ and $t = \tilde{t}t_o $.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two factors and two degrees of freedom, it should be possible to make both factors $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your equation to work, $\beta$ must have dimensions $\frac{[Mass]}{[Length]}$, assuming $m$ is the mass of your object. (in the future, please define all parameters and variables used in the question). Let's define $\frac{\beta}{m} = B$. We know that $B$ must have unit $\frac{1}{Length}$. We also know that $g$, the gravitational acceleration, has units $\frac{[Length]}{[Time]^2}$.

Now, theoretically, we can choose any reference velocity $v_0$ and any reference time $t_0$, divide $v(t)$ and $t$ by the references, and get a nondimensional equation. But what we REALLY want is a nondimensional equation which minimizes the number of parameters floating around: we basically want the equation to be "nice."

Let's leave $t_0$ undetermined to start. Observe that it MUST have unit $[Time]$ by definition. So a good bet to minimize extra parameters is to choose $v_0$ to equal some $L$ divided by $t_0$, where $L$ has unit length. Now, we don't have an immediately obvious time scale. However, we DO have an immediately apparent length scale: $\frac{1}{B}$. I'm going to assume $B$ is positive, so let's just see what happens if we say $\tilde{v}\frac{1}{Bt_0} = v$, $\tilde{t}t_0 = t$

$$\frac{d\tilde{v}}{d\tilde{t}}\frac{1}{Bt^2_0} = -g-B\frac{\tilde{v}|\tilde{v}|}{B^2t^2_0}$$

$$\frac{d\tilde{v}}{d\tilde{t}} = -t^2_0Bg-\tilde{v}|\tilde{v}|$$

Note that we have not actually CHOSEN $t_0$ yet, so we can choose it to be whatever we want. We want to choose it so that it's positive (because that's how time works), to have dimension $[Time]$, and to make the equation as simple as possible.

Notice that $Bg$ has units $\frac{1}{[Time]^2}$, so $\sqrt{Bg}$ has units $\frac{1}{[Time]}$. If we choose $t_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Bg}}$, then we get the final nondimensional equation:

$$\frac{d\tilde{v}}{d\tilde{t}} = -1-\tilde{v}|\tilde{v}|$$